# Select an Eclipse 4 RCP Part in Unit Test.

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-rcp, e4

I´m currently writing Tests for my Eclipse 4 RCP Application.
For one Test it is necessary to select the Part (Part2) during the Test. I can dynamically create it and invoke the Post Construct Method, but the Part itself is not selected.
I tried to include an Injection for a PartService but regardless if I try to do it in the TestCase or the Part itself, the PartService is null.
I also thought about using SWTBot, but I guess it´s not possible to select Parts there because the Part itself is no SWT Widget.
Any ideas how to programatically ensure the selection of the Part during the Test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below code, two view parts are opened (and selected): `MemoryView` and then `DisplayView`. Method `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.showView(String)` gets a view part ID as the argument and opens the view when it is not opened. The part is always selected in this method call.

```
public class PluginTestCase {

    @Test
    public void showView() {
        Display display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
        Shell shell = display.getActiveShell();
        // Create a new thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            runUICode(display);
        });
        thread.start();

        // Enter the UI message loop
        while (!shell.isDisposed() && thread.isAlive()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the code in a separate thread.
     * 
     * @param display
     *            the display which handles UI modifications
     */
    private void runUICode(Display display) {
        closeIntro(display);
        showView(display, "org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.DisplayView");
        showView(display, "org.eclipse.debug.ui.MemoryView");
    }

    /**
     * Closes the introduction part.
     */
    private void closeIntro(Display display) {
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                IIntroPart introPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getIntroManager().getIntro();
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getIntroManager().closeIntro(introPart);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Shows view of the given ID in the current perspective. The view gets
     * focus (is selected).
     * 
     * @param display
     *            the display object
     * @param viewId
     *            the ID of the view to be shown
     */
    private void showView(Display display, String viewId) {
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                    // Show and select the view
                    activePage.showView(viewId);
                } catch (WorkbenchException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

The code doesn't leverage SWTBot but custom message loop.

Be sure you run the test as JUnit Plug-in Test.

Comment: Forking a background thread and then running the UI code on the display thread is not necessary. If you make sure that the launch config has _Run in UI thread_ enabled (which is the default), it is enough to call `activePage.showView()` etc.on the current (UI) thrad.